# Composer error Could not open input file: composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having a problem with Composer. I have Composer installed globally on my machine. I am trying to install intercom using composer. I tried the command:

```
php composer.phar require intercom/intercom-php
```

but that returned "Could not open input file: composer.phar"

After investigating and reading the issues others have had I then tried

```
php composer require intercom/intercom-php
```

but that returned "Could not open input file: composer"

As I stated, I have Composer installed globally on my machine. I can type in the command "composer update" and it works from any directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you got composer installed globally and `composer update` just works then get rid of `php` and instead of

```
php composer require intercom/intercom-php
```

just do

```
composer require intercom/intercom-php
```

The reason  why former form does not work while the latter does is that you are invoking `php` executable and pass `composer` as its argument. It is then treated by php binary as script file path and as there's neither relative nor absolute path segments used, just file name, then file `composer` is expected to exist in current working directory which is no the case. In second invocation, your shell will look for `composer` binary in all known paths defined in `$PATH` env variable.

If you wonder where `composer` executable  realy lives, you can  use

```
which composer
```

Or on Windows

```
where composer
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Also helped! Thanks :)